# How to show inner content in list item outside of that list item without being covered up by descending list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I have a grid with list items you can click on to toggle the inner content to display itself - http://jsfiddle.net/TimmyTodd/SUf5y/1/

Each list item has an overflow of visible, but the inner content gets covered up by any list item that comes after it (even with the z-index of the inner content set to be on top of "li").

Is there any way to make that inner content appear on top of all list items?

Here's my CSS:

```
li {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    float: left;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

    overflow: visible;
}
.innerContentToShow {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;

    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;

    border: 10px solid #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.innerContentToShow p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 28px;
}
```

And some of my HTML list code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <div class="innerContentToShow">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="innerContentToShow">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="innerContentToShow">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: have you tried to change the z-index of the clicked 'li' itself?

Comment: brilliant. worked. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You must set the z-index of the clicked 'li' higher and in return the former clicked 'li' back.

Here is the example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SUf5y/2/)

And here the script:

```
var oldli;
$('li').click(
    function(){
        $(oldli).toggleClass('displayNone displayBlock');
        $(oldli).css("z-index","1");
        $(this).toggleClass('displayBlock displayNone');
        $(this).css("z-index","5");
        oldli=$(this);
    }
);
```